# How can I stop PHP the while loop to repeat and cover old data?

Tags: php, jquery, csv, while-loop, barcode

I am new to PHP, so I want the while loop the result every times is different because I fetch data from CSV file, so it should not be all the data is same.

> This is my code

```
<div style="margin: 1%">


            <?php
            //include 'barcode128.php';
            require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                if (($csvfile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($csvdata = fgetcsv($csvfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                        $colcount = count($csvdata);

                        if($colcount!=5) {
                            $error = 'Column count incorrect';
                        } else {

                            /*$product = $csvdata[0];
                            $product_id = $csvdata[1];
                            $rate = $csvdata[2];
                            $description = $csvdata[3];
                            $image = $csvdata[4];
                            $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

                                echo '<div class="wrapper">';
                                echo '<div class="a"><img src="data:image;base64,'.$imageData.'" width="50"/>
                                      <div><b>Item: '.$product.'</b></div>
                                      <div><svg id="barcode"><script>JsBarcode("#barcode", "'.$product_id.'",{
                                      format: "code128",width: 1,height: 35,fontOptions: "bold",marginRight:30});</script></svg></div><span><b>Price: '.$rate.' </b></span><div><span><b>Desc: </b>'.$description.'</span></div></p></span>
                                      </div></div>';
                            */

                            $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($csvdata[4]));

                                echo '<div class="wrapper">';
                                echo '<div class="a"><img src="data:image;base64,'.$imageData.'" width="50"/>
                                      <div><b>Item: '.$csvdata[0].'</b></div>
                                      <div><svg id="barcode"><script>JsBarcode("#barcode", "'.$csvdata[1].'",{
                                      format: "code128",width: 1,height: 35,fontOptions: "bold",marginRight:30,font:"arial"});</script></svg></div><span><b>Price: '.$csvdata[2].' </b></span><div><span><b>Desc: </b>'.$csvdata[3].'</span></div></p></span>
                                      </div></div>';

                        }

                    }
                    fclose($csvfile);
                }
            ?>

    </div>
```

---

> The result of the current code:
>   [image-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3aaE.png)

---

> The CSV file: 
>   [image-csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkFDf.png)

---

> This is what I want the result:
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHT81.png)

So, how can I make the result can loop every times and break it, then loop the next data from the CSV file? Thank you

Comment: Hey, could you add the code where the barcode is displayed? That seems to the problem, not with your current code.

Comment: @Ice76 The code I got from this website: https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/
Thank you.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($csvdata);` inside the loop to confirm that the values are actually what you expect them to be?

Comment: @PatrickQ I put `var_dump($csvdata);` before `fclose($csvfile);`, show the array is fine, but after `fclose($csvfile);` it show `bool(false)`. It is normal?

Comment: Your call to `fclose()` is _outside_ of the loop.  You want to check the values _inside_ the loop so that you can see what they are each time through the loop.  Put it right before your `$imageData = base64_encode....` or something like that.

Comment: @PatrickQ I put it before the `$imageData = base64_encode....` Only show one result, and then put `var_dump($csvdata);` inside the loop, it show the array is fine, is same as my CSV the data

Comment: `svg id="barcode">`  That's probably the problem.  HTML element IDs should be unique, and _must_ be unique when CSS or Javascript are referencing elements by ID.  Your barcode Javascript is probably doing that (in fact, I see that it is `JsBarcode("#barcode"`).  You need to make the element ID unique, each time through the loop, and then pass that unique ID to the Javascript call (or see if the barcode library allows you to pass a different reference, such as a traversal-based reference.

Comment: @PatrickQ Sorry, would you mind to should me the code? Because my coding is not so good, thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating multiple `svg` elements with the same id.  You are then using this single id in your `JsBarcode()` call.  By doing this, the Javascript will always act on the *first* element with this id.

To remedy this, we must create elements with unique ids, and then use this unique id in each Javascript call.

Since you have `$product_id = $csvdata[1];` in your commented-out code, this answer is going assume that `$csvdata[1]` is unique per row.

Inside of your `echo`, change

`<div><svg id="barcode"><script>JsBarcode("#barcode", "'.$csvdata[1].'",{`

to

`<div><svg id="barcode_'.$csvdata[1].'"><script>JsBarcode("#barcode_'.$csvdata[1].'", "'.$csvdata[1].'",{`